# Drawing inferences from word counts

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out if there is a good model that can connect word counts to classifying whether or not a person might go to an event. Here's the description: I have users, and events. 100 features in events are word counts; I don't know what each word is, but I know that feature 1 is the most used word stem of all event descriptions, feature 2 is the second most used word stem of all event descriptions... so on and so forth. I know which users go to which events. I just can't seem to find a way to incorporate these word count features into my current model. Does anyone know of a good direction to send me off in?

Comment: What is your current model?

Comment: GradientBoosting is being applied to all the other data that was given me.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is also known as the "[bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)" (or really bag of stems) model.  You can actually just include the word counts as features in your model.  The model will then see if the presence/absence of a given word influences a person's probabilities of attending an event.

For example, maybe events with the word "concert" in their title attract more attendees than events with the word "bookclub." (Is this a Kaggle competition, btw?)

It sounds like you've already stemmed your words, which is great.  Some other suggestions are:

1. [Remove stopwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)
2. [Principle components analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) on the word frequencies
3. [tf-idf weighting of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)
4. [ngrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)

Answer (score 0):

How about a random forest classifier (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest)? Im not too experienced but I think it should fit what you are describing quite well.